TensorFlow image_dataset_from_directory not mapping labels correctly
I am using the following code to read *.jpg files from the
"labeled_data_dir"
Labels are age of person.
*
*training_dataset= tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    labeled_data_dir,
    image_size=image_size,  # Resize images (adjust as needed)
    batch_size=batch_size       # Batch size for training (adjust as needed)
    seed=9,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training"
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int"
)*




The files in directory are structured under each sub-directory, where sub-directory is name of labels.
Function also prints it as
"Found 10137 files belonging to 80 classes"
But when I try to see the images in loaded dataset, every image is the first subdirectory name, which is not the case.
If I remove that subdirectory then the label changes to next subdirectory name.
Code I am using to display Images and labels is:
*for images, labels in training_dataset.take(1):  # Take only one batch
    for i in range(9):  # Display the first 9 images from the batch
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)   # Create subplots in a 3x3 grid
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))  # Show the image
        plt.title(class_names[labels[i].numpy().argmax()]) #Show the class name
        plt.axis("off") #Disable the axes
plt.show()*


What am I doing wrong?

label_mode is already int, you probably don't need argmax in plt.title

Frightera is right, if you have ints as labels and use argmax() on them, you'll always get index 0.
